# Lucene: build a query by tokenizing a string and pass

Tags: lucene

I need to extract single terms from a string to build a query using `BooleanQuery`.
I'm using `QueryParser.parse()` method for it, this is my code snippet:

```java
booleanQuery.add(
    new QueryParser(
            org.apache.lucene.util.Version.LUCENE_40, 
            "tags", 
            new WhitespaceAnalyzer(org.apache.lucene.util.Version.LUCENE_40)
    ).parse("tag1 tag2 tag3"), 
    BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

I'm however wondering if this is correct way to pass single terms to booleanQuery.

`QueryParser.parse` method returns a `SrndQuery` object, which I directly pass to `booleanQuery.add()` method.

Not sure if this is correct. Should I extract single terms instead from `SrndQuery`... or something like that, and invoke `booleanQuery.add()` several times ?

**Update**: printed query

```
*.*:*.* title:Flickrmeetup_01 description:Michael description:R. description:Ross tags:rochester tags:ny tags:usa tags:flickrmeetup tags:king76 tags:eos350d tags:canon50mmf14 tags:mikros tags:canon tags:ef tags:50mm tags:f14 tags:usm tags:canonef50mmf14 tags:canonef50mmf14usm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should extract the tokens, wrap each one in a Term, then create a TermQuery for it, then add the TermQuery to the BooleanQuery. SrndQuery is abstract anyway, so I guess your current code would create an instance of a subclass, which is probably not what you mean to do. You may want to create your own custom QueryParser for this.

Comment: well I've been suggested to print the query and this is the result.. apparently it works: the same field is repeated for each term. But please could you give a look at the printed query (added to the question) and let me know if I'm correct ?

Comment: @Patrick - It looks fine. I do not like the global part (.:*.*) - it may hurt performance. I suggest you check the result set to see if you get what you expect, and check performance as well.

Comment: OK, well I guess that .:*.* is because of MatchAllDocsQuery